# Why does linear media produce a $1/2$ factor when using partial derivatives?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, differentiation

Oftentimes in Jackson's text there are certain remarks made about linear media (see pg. 226, ed. 2, for example) and there is often a simplification of partial differentials or variations made. For example, on 226, Jackson states
$$
\mathbf{E}\cdot\frac{\partial \mathbf{D}}{\partial t}+\mathbf{H}\cdot\frac{\partial\mathbf{B}}{\partial t}\to \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathbf{D}+\mathbf{B}\cdot\mathbf{H})
$$
which implies
$$
\mathbf{E}\cdot\frac{\partial \mathbf{D}}{\partial t}\to\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathbf{D})
$$
and
$$
\mathbf{H}\cdot\frac{\partial\mathbf{B}}{\partial t}\to\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\mathbf{H}\cdot\mathbf{B})
$$
but I do not know why these two assumptions are valid. Is there a mathematical reason? Another example, a few pages back, is when he writes
$$
\mathbf{H}\cdot\delta\mathbf{A}=\frac{1}{2}\delta(\mathbf{H}\cdot\mathbf{A}).
$$
Again, I am not sure where the one half factor comes from. Any comments or answers would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: When you take the time derivative, you have to use the product rule. This leads to two equal terms and thus a factor of $2$, which cancels the $1/2$.

Comment: @knzhou Yes I assumed so-- but my issue is that it does not seem obvious that $\partial\mathbf{D}/\partial t=\partial\mathbf{E}/\partial t$ unless $\partial\mathbf{P}/\partial t=0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\mathbf{D} = \epsilon \mathbf{E}$, then

$$\frac12 \frac{\partial}{\partial t} (\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathbf{D}) = \frac{\epsilon}{2} \frac{\partial}{\partial t} (\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathbf{E}) = \epsilon \mathbf{E} \cdot \frac{\partial \mathbf{E}}{\partial t} = \mathbf{E} \cdot \frac{\partial \mathbf{D}}{\partial t}$$